# termios settings on USB modem serial get ignored

Tags: c++, serial-port, termios

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and try to read AT commands from a modem. I need to do some changes to the serial interface to properly communicate these commands. However, if I try setting the baudrate, it stays the same. I use the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DEVICE "/dev/ttyUSB2"

using namespace std;

class ATException : public exception {
public:
    ATException(string msg) : msg(msg) { }

    virtual const char* what() const throw() {
        return msg.c_str();
    }

private:
    string msg;
};

void set_speeds(int fd, speed_t ispeed, speed_t ospeed) {
    struct termios term_args;
    int result = tcgetattr(fd, &term_args);
    if (result != 0) throw ATException ("unable to tcgetattr device");

    term_args.c_cflag = CS8 | CREAD | CLOCAL;

    if (cfsetispeed(&term_args, ispeed) != 0) throw ATException("error setting i speed");

    if (cfsetospeed(&term_args, ospeed) != 0) throw ATException("error setting o speed");

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &term_args) != 0) throw ATException("unable to set device attr");
}

void get_speeds(int fd, speed_t& ispeed, speed_t& ospeed) {
    struct termios term_args;
    memset(&term_args, 0, sizeof term_args);
    int result = tcgetattr(fd, &term_args);
    if (result != 0) throw ATException ("unable to tcgetattr device");

    ispeed = cfgetispeed(&term_args);
    ospeed = cfgetospeed(&term_args);
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    speed_t ispeed;
    speed_t ospeed;
    struct termios term_args;

    int device_fd = open(DEVICE, O_RDWR);
    if (device_fd == -1) {
        cerr << "unable to open device " << DEVICE << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    try {
        cout << "  B9600 speed: " <<   B9600 << endl;
        cout << " B38400 speed: " <<  B38400 << endl;
        cout << "B115200 speed: " << B115200 << endl;
        cout << "B230400 speed: " << B230400 << endl << endl;

        get_speeds(device_fd, ispeed, ospeed);
        cout << "current i speed: " << ispeed << endl;
        cout << "current o speed: " << ospeed << endl;

        speed_t test_speeds [] = {B38400, B115200, B230400};
        for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(test_speeds) / sizeof(speed_t)); i++) { 
            cout << "setting speeds to " << test_speeds[i] << endl;
            set_speeds(device_fd, test_speeds[i], test_speeds[i]);
            get_speeds(device_fd, ispeed, ospeed);
            cout << "current i speed: " << ispeed << endl;
            cout << "current o speed: " << ospeed << endl;
        }

        int chars_written;
        // writing/reading
        chars_written = write(device_fd, "AT\r", 3);
        cout << "written " << chars_written << " chars" << endl;

        char read_buf [16];
        int chars_read = read(device_fd, read_buf, sizeof(read_buf));
        cout << "read (" << chars_read << "): " << read_buf << endl;
        usleep(50000);
        chars_read = read(device_fd, read_buf, sizeof(read_buf));
        cout << "read (" << chars_read << "): " << read_buf << endl;

    } catch (ATException& e) {
        cerr << "ERROR: " << e.what() << DEVICE << endl;
    }

    close(device_fd);
}
```

If I execute this, I get the following output:

```cpp
  B9600 speed: 13
 B38400 speed: 15
B115200 speed: 4098
B230400 speed: 4099

current i speed: 13
current o speed: 13
setting speeds to 15
current i speed: 13
current o speed: 13
setting speeds to 4098
current i speed: 13
current o speed: 13
setting speeds to 4099
current i speed: 13
current o speed: 13
written 3 chars
...
```

It seems like the baudrate hasn't changed. Why is this? Did I miss something? Thanks for help. Let me know if there's something which needs to be clarified, please!

If you consider down rating my question, please also leave a comment why, so I can improve my question or learn for the future. Thanks.

Comment: did you try running your application as root?

Comment: @nivpeled yes, I did. The result was the same.

Comment: why dont we see this print in the log?         cout << "setting speeds to B115200" << endl;

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I changed it in the code for clarity but didn't compile and run again before posting the output.

Comment: please print the value of B115200 in         cout << "setting speeds to B115200" << endl;

Comment: also try to set to B38400. it is possible 115200 is somehow not supported by this API or by the device

Comment: I changed the code and also updated the output of the current version. Seems like none of the settings has an effect. Or is it possible that the the baudrate can't be changed because it's a USB-serial (/dev/ttyUSBX)?

Comment: *"Or is it possible that the the baudrate can't be changed because it's a USB-serial (/dev/ttyUSBX)?"* -- Perform a sanity test: instead of your code, use the `stty` command.  BTW the answer should be "no, the baudrate can be changed."

Comment: The code you posted does not compile cleanly on a PC with `16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP`.  There are three errors such as  `test.cc:59:15: error: ‘exit’ was not declared in this scope` and `/usr/include/c++/5/exception:64:13: error:   overriding ‘virtual std::exception::~exception() throw ()’`

Comment: @sawdust Just copied this to a file on my machine (Ubuntu 18.04LTS), it compiles fine. `g++ --version: 
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0 ...`

Comment: I used another PC with same version of compiler as yours, and your program compiled okay.  Program produces the expected output for FTDI and Prolific USB-to-serial adapters.  You therefore should focus your attention on your adapter.